# Powershell: Search for string at end of one line and beginning of next line, and output line number

Tags: regex, powershell

How do I Search to find a line with only a ~ "tilde" character, followed by the next line that does NOT BEGIN with a ~ tilde.

This is for a large multi-record text file, and normally every multi-record is separated (delimited) by a record with just a ~ tilde character.  I would like to find all missing delimiters in the file. All the records in the file end with a CRLF.

Sample text file to search.  In this sample file, the first multi-record is at lines 1 and 2, followed by the tilde ~ delimiter, then lines 4 to 6 is the next multi-record followed by another ~ delimiter at line 7.
The script should find the error at line 8 because it should begin with a ~ followed by more text (as in lines 1 and 4).

*MyTextFile.txt*:

```
~A123~,~800-123-1234~,~800-345-6789~

SAMPLE TEXT HERE

~

~A100~,~800-123-1234~,~800-345-6789~

SAMPLE TEXT HERE

MORE SAMPLE TEXT HERE

~

SAMPLE TEXT HERE

MORE SAMPLE TEXT HERE
```

The following PowerShell code is finding the "Value" with just the tilde followed by the 1st character in the next line "S", but it's not displaying the line number, which I need so I can delete the remaining text after the ~ line.

Current code:

```
$MYFILE = Get-Content MyTextFile.txt -Raw
[regex]$rx="[~]`r`n[^~]"
$rx.Match($MYFILE)
```

Output:

```
Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 136
Length   : 4
Value    : ~
           S
```

I have a working script in Linux BASH, but I'm new to Powershell.

Comment: I believe you ask for `'(?m)^~\r?\n(?!~)'`, but you will need something else in fact, if you want to replace more than just this match. What is your expected output?

Comment: It can be the entire line where it found the value "S", and the line number.  So in my sample text file, it should otuput the line "SAMPLE TEXT HERE" and the line number, which is line 8.  It does not have to replace anything.  Just output the line and line number of the matching REGEX.

Comment: You can't output the line number, and you do not need it in 99.9% of cases. To match the line after a `~` line, you may use `'(?m)(?<=^~\r?\n)[^~].*'`

Comment: Thank you.  That last code is matching now and returning the entire line.  Maybe I can create a counter to find the line number where it matched?

Comment: It is not possible with regex, it does not know of any lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) for this:

```
Select-String -Path MyTextFile.txt -Pattern '^~$' -Context 1 | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Context.Postcontext -notmatch '^~') {
        throw "Error: Line $($_.LineNumber+1) is missing the delimiter"
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`Select-String` can read a text file line-by-line using the `-Path` command and perform a regex match based on `-Pattern` value. Using `-Context 1` returns the line above and below each match.

The returned object is a `MatchInfo` object with properties `LineNumber` (for the matched line) and `Context`. `Context` is a `MatchInfoContext` object with  `PreContext` (line before the match) and `PostContext` (line after the match) properties.

Comment: Thank you AdminOfThings.  Your explanation is making more sense to me now.  This is now working for what is needed.  I made a minor change to your code.  It is now finding All the errors in the file after I changed the "throw" error line to ""Error: Line $($_.LineNumber+1) is missing the comma delimited record".  I just need it to list all the line numbers where the matches are found.  And this is a working example in Linux BASH: pcregrep -Mn '[~]\r\n[^~]' MyTextFile.txt

Comment: This is now my working code:  Select-String -Path MyTextFile.txt -Pattern '^~$' -Context 1 | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Context.Postcontext -notmatch '^~') {
  "Error: Line $($_.LineNumber+1) is missing the comma delimited record"
    }